# Wireless hard blocked on lenovo s205

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ati, lenovo

Okay so Im really frustrated...
For like the last couple of months I was running the early release of 12.04, but then I had to clear my hard drive and finally upgraded to the actual release of 12.04. Now, my wireless won't work.

With `rfkill list`, it shows that my wireless LAN is hard blocked but NOT soft blocked. I've tried everything, the hardware switch is on, `rfkill unblock all` won't do anything and there is nothing in my BIOS restricting wifi, and, to make it even more confusing, if I just boot from a USB, wireless works fine. For some reason it just won't work if it is installed.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

some Lenovo models have a hardware switch - mine (G570) has one to left of the touchpad just on the underside. It is sometimes possible to accidentally trigger this without realizing that you have done so.

Also, some drivers for wireless devices can have variable performance on different versions of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to google your wifi card + rfkill. When asking questions, please add some more info, like output from `lspci | grep 802`. We need to know what card and drivers we are dealing with.

I had the same problem, btw. And I got fixed by me just poking around with `rfkill unblock all` and `rfkill unblock wifi`. I wish I knew exactly what made it work, but after a while I successfully unblocked everything, I rebooted, and have never had an issue with this again - so do not give up! Just try to push the wifi button, and the rfkill commands to see if you cant unblock it, and then reboot.

Some have had effect from pushing the wifi button while booting.

My problem was with a Atheros wifi card.